# SSIS: how to use a linked server:

Tags: ssis, odbc

I have added a linked server through MS SQL Server Management Studio successfully.  It's name is SQL2_Link.

When I go to add a connection as ADO.NET Connection in SSIS, it will not show up in the list of available options.

How can I add this as an option for an ADO.NET Connection in SSIS.

I am using SQL Server 2008, BIDS 2008.

Thanks...!

EDIT

The Linked Server is using MS OLE DB Provider for ODBC DRIVERS

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't want to try to connect to the Linked Server in SSIS - just create a new connection to the database.  If you've set the linked server up then I assume you have all the connection details - create a new ADO.NET connection with these details and use that as your source or destination as required.

Comment: would i use .net providers for oledb or just .net providers?

Comment: i think i know whatyou mean i am getting lost in the connection manager