# SSIS: How to access a linked server?

Tags: ssis

I just want to create a  connnection to a linked server i created to an oracle db.

How could i access a linked server?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to this answer - [SSIS: how to use a linked server:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411834/ssis-how-to-use-a-linked-server) - you want to create a new connection directly to Oracle rather than go via the linked server.  You'll need the Oracle tools installed however.